# How can I pass data from one export function to another export function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a function in cloud functions that picks the user email from my flutter app and I want to pass it to a function that uses the user email to create a firestore document when posted from an external client so that i can store the data in the specific user's document in firestore. I am new to javascript and I am using cloud functions to run the backend code of my flutter app.

I have tried using global variables but i keep getting the stored value as undefined in the `exports.mpesa` function but in the `exports.getUser` function, it updates. Any help will be appreciated.

This is what my index.js file looks like

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
let loggedInUser;

function convertTZ(date, tzString) {
 return new Date((typeof date === "string" ? new Date(date) : date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: tzString}));   
}

exports.getUser = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
 console.log(loggedInUser); 
 loggedInUser = data;
 console.log(loggedInUser);
});

exports.mpesa = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  try{
   let date_ob = Date();
   const data = request.body;
   const date = convertTZ(date_ob,"Africa/Nairobi");
   prettydata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
   console.log("Mpesa info");
   console.log(loggedInUser);
   functions.logger.info(data);
   console.log("Done1");
   functions.logger.info(prettydata.Body.stkCallback.ResultCode);
   console.log("Done2");
   admin.firestore().collection('transactions').doc(`${date}`).set(data);
   admin.firestore().collection('transactions').doc(`${loggedInUser}`).set(data);
   console.log("Done3");
  }
  catch(e){
   functions.logger.info(e);
  }
});
```

and i am calling the getUser function on flutter as shown below

```
await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getUser').call(loggedInUser.email);
```

and a package (https://pub.dev/packages/mpesa_flutter_plugin) sends the data to the callback URL of the `get.mpesa` function

The logs from the output look as shown

```
getUser
Function execution started
12:05:55.673 am
getUser
Callable request verification passed
12:05:55.674 am
getUser
undefined
12:05:55.674 am
getUser
edward@mmw.co.ke
12:05:55.755 am
getUser
Function execution took 1489 ms, finished with status code: 200
12:06:03.373 am
mpesa
Function execution started
12:06:03.593 am
mpesa
Mpesa info
12:06:03.673 am
mpesa
undefined
12:06:03.674 am
mpesa
{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"ResultCode":1032,"ResultDesc":"Request cancelled by user","MerchantRequestID":"22982-12102077-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_011120210005554833"}}}
12:06:03.674 am
mpesa
Done1
12:06:03.674 am
mpesa
1032
12:06:03.674 am
mpesa
Done2
12:06:06.105 am
mpesa
Done3
12:07:03.375 am
mpesa
Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the data to your MPESA function ?

Comment: It is activated externally by a mobile money payment platform. It is a callback for them to send the payment data.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options how to proceed with this. You can't really simply call another cloud function like that.

**1. Separate your code logic from your "cloud functions"**
This means putting your code into separate JavaScript function and just calling that code from the cloud function.

```js
function A(...){
//...
}

exports.getUser = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  // ... call function A
  A(...)
});

function B(){
 // ...
}

exports.mpesa = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  // ... call function B
  B(...)
  // And in case we want to call the logic from function A we can again call it here
  A(...)
});
```

**2. Keeping the cloud functions separate and triggering another function**
You can trigger another cloud functions several ways. If you want to have it as onRequest function you could just call the function url from another function.

```
// for example a GET function
fetch("https://us-east4-your-project-prod.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction?data=mydata")
```

Or you could use POST request...

But in your case, I would just move my code logic into separate JavaScript function and have 2 triggers for this function. One could be the external trigger and second one could be from the app. Both cloud functions would do some "logic" and than call the final javascript function to save the data.

Comment: I am relatively new to cloud functions so i've gone with the first one as i've not understood the second one quite well and gone with the two functions. I am still getting 'undefined' in the logs.
The `mpesa` function is initiated externally by a mobile money platform. the only function I initiate is the `getUser` one.